# For loop string iteration does not work when checking for NUL with "less than" operator

Tags: c, for-loop

Why does this work:

```
char Word[]="monkey";
for (int Index = 0; Word[Index] != '\0'; Index++)
{
    printf("%c", Word[Index]);
}
```

while this does not?

```
char Word[]="monkey";
for (int Index = 0; Word[Index] < '\0'; Index++)
{
    printf("%c", Word[Index]);
}
```

To be honest, I do not see any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `char` is a signed type, ASCII characters are **non-negative** and go from 0 to 127. Therefore, in the second example, your condition will never evaluate to true since all characters in the string are ASCII characters.

If you really want to use something other than `!=`, your only option is `>`:

```
char Word[] = "monkey";
for (int Index = 0; Word[Index] > '\0'; Index++)
{
    printf("%c", Word[Index]);
}
```

NOTE: while this works, it might be confusing and error prone, you should always prefer `!= '\0'`.

Comment: Got it
Word[Index] < '\0'; means that it will never be true since end of text ('\0') is decimal 03, and real keyboard characters are higher values in the ASCII table. Could you confirm?

Comment: @max Yes, exactly. One little correctio: `\0` is decimal 0.

Comment: Oh, I came across "End of text" which is decimal 3. Where do we apply it?

Comment: @max that's a special control character for old communication protocols, you usually don't see it nowdays. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

By definition, there can be no value "lower" than null - which is what `\0` is and what your `<` is checking. What the limit part of your `for` loop is checking for is that you haven't reached the null terminator in the string, so `!=` is the only correct check to make (unless you wanted the extra step of creating a limit variable which is `strlen(Word)` and checking for Index < limit).

Comment: *"By definition, there can be no value "lower" than null"* - well, `-1` is lower than `NULL` really. *"which is what `\0` is"* - not really, `\0` is the ***NUL*** ASCII character (not to be confused with `NULL`, the very famous special pointer value). *"`!=` is the only correct check to make"* - works fine with `>` too, since OP's string is ASCII.

Comment: `char` may be signed and have negative values. The C standard requires members of the basic execution character set to be nonnegative, but other characters may be negative.